# Limit the contents shared by the author

Tags: drupal-6

I am using Drupal 6.16 and following is my query.

I have a content type, the author of that content can share it to other registered users of the site.

And for sharing i am using **user-reference** in cck

I need to limit the author on sharing the content, the limit should depends upon the type of role taken by that user.

Eg If user have ROLE-5 then he/she can share only 5 contents of content type "A"
   And if the user have ROLE-10 then he/she can share only 100 contents of content type "A"

S0, just wanted to know, is there any module which provides this kind of functionality or i have to create my own custom module.

Cheers!!
Vivek

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a custom module.

If you use hook_form_alter() you can add another validation function to your form. That function would look at the number of elements in your user reference field and depending on the role of the author it would throw an error if the number of elements is greater that the number allowed for the role.

Here is a page that somewhat describes what to do
http://fleetthought.com/adding-additional-cck-validation-function-field-using-hookformalter